# voting to reopen, the consultant that doesn't know how to get paid and prefers crypto

Tags: discussion, votes

I edited this closed question by removing some irrelevant information, hoping others will help me reopen or suggest further edits to subsequently reopen

[What services will people pay for with crypto in 2020?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131099/what-services-will-people-pay-for-with-crypto-in-2020/131100#131100)

It is ultimately about a consultant with some software development skills that wants to get paid and prefers crypto.

A lot of the comments ask irrelevant details about payment conditions because personal finance forums are still allergic to the word "bitcoin" or anything crypto. OP also has an odd perception as if legal services paid in crypto needs a disclaimer or are an outlier, I removed that.

I felt I was able to give a relevant answer for a relevant question. So I removed some of the red herrings from the question, just like the people that closed the question had asked "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question."

I also changed the title. Feel free to compare to the original post for more context, and suggest a different title.

Answer (score 3):

The question is basically asking for advice on finding a job. I mean, yes, that's about making money, but I can't see how it's a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The OP of that question accuses everyone trying to help or get more information of either being unhelpful or insulting. That said, the premise of his question makes no sense to me. He has no idea what kind of work he can offer, but wants to be paid in bitcoin. Isn’t that putting the cart before the horse? I’m abstaining from a vote, so far one to reopen, one to delete and be done with it.